# textbox values to store in a excel sheet with a loop

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim RI As Integer
Dim CI As Integer
Dim X As Integer
Dim texts() As Variant

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
RI = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(RI, 1).Select
CI = ActiveCell.Column

texts = Array(Text5.Text, Text6.Text, Text7.Text, Text8.Text, Text9.Text,Text10.Text,   Text11.Text, Text12.Text, Text13.Text, Text14.Text, Text15.Text, Text16.Text, Text17.Text, Text18.Text, Text19.Text)
For CI = 2 To 16
For X = 0 To UBound(texts)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(RI, CI).Value = texts(X)
Next X
Next CI
```

Dear Friends, 
   I have to get values from 15 text boxes from text5.text to 1ext19.text and store it in a excel sheet from columns B to P. When i follow the above code it returns only the text19.text in all the cells of the row. Kindly suggest me friends...

Comment: Thank you so much Siddharth Rout... It works!!!

Answer (score 1):

No need for the loops. Use `.Resize`. Here is an example

```
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
texts = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", _
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15")

'~~> Not needed
'For CI = 2 To 16
    'For X = 0 To UBound(texts)
        'ActiveSheet.Cells(RI, CI).Value = texts(X)
    'Next X
'Next CI

ActiveSheet.Cells(RI, CI).Resize(, 15).Value = texts
```

**EDIT**

If you **still** want to use a loop then use it like this

```
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
texts = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", _
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15")

j = 2

'~~> Not needed
For X = 0 To UBound(texts)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(RI, j).Value = texts(X)
    j = j + 1
Next X
```

In your code, the column was not being incremented correctly.

Comment: ++ for eliminating the loop